# Worker Role instance unhealthy

Tags: azure

One of my deployed worker role shows as unhealthy, although its working perfectly (doing the desired job for every single request). I cannot see any runtime exception there and status is displayed as recyling.

Can anybody give me a hint, Why this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow either of (or both) the ways to get more insight information about what is going on in your app.

- Configure Diagnostics - [a good article on how to configure it](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-monitor-a-cloud-service/).
- Enable Remote Desktop - [How to configure a remote access to role instances](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-configure-a-cloud-service/#remoteaccess)

Collect data for some time - 1/2 or 1 hour. Inspect diagnostics logs. Log-on with Remote Desktop and check Windows Event Log. Better instrument your code.

Recycling of a Worker Role is typically invoked by exiting the `Run` method of `RoleEntryPoint` implementation (usually `WorkerRole.cs`). You shall never exit this method. An unhandled exception may be the cause for `Run` method termination. Unhandled exception in .NET runtime are usually logged into the Windows Event Log.